# Use of commas and "or" with "e.g."

Tags: punctuation, commas

In a book (Clean Architecture, Robert C. Martin, page 46) I read

> (e.g., jar files, DLLs, or Gem files)

I wonder about the use of commas and *or*. I would have expected

> (e.g. jar files, DLLs or Gem files)

Are the two additional commas wrong, irrelevant or do they provide additional meaning here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to use commas in lists before the conjunction?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/is-it-necessary-to-use-commas-in-lists-before-the-conjunction)

Comment: The OP is also asking about the use of commas after 'e.g.' If this is answered then the answer should also include the use of commas after 'i.e.' I think that it is worthwhile having an answer to those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage* (Peters, 2004):

> The punctuation before and after e.g. has long been the subject of prescription. A comma used to be considered necessary after it, and is still usual, according to the Chicago Manual (2003). But most style guides now dispense with the following comma, and simply emphasize having one *before* it. Other punctuation marks, such as a dash, colon or opening parenthesis could equally well come *before* it, depending on the structure of the sentence.

Punctuation with *or*. This is simply a matter of whether to put a comma before *or* when it introduces the last of a series of alternatives. The issue is the same as for *and* in the same position. See the [discussion of the serial comma](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/is-it-necessary-to-use-commas-in-lists-before-the-conjunction).